# Tengo un problema con llamadas a clases php usando ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy llamando a un archivo usando ajax, y dentro de ese archivo estoy haciendo una llamada a una clase php, y parece ser que no me está funcionando.

Este sería un ejemplo del contenido del archivo que quiero cargar desde ajax:

```
<div>
<?php
$llamarClase = new Clase();

$llamarMetodo = $llamarClase->metodoClase();
?>
</div>
```

¿Una ayudita, por favor? Gracias :)

Comment: `Clase` debe estar definida en algun lugar antes de usarse. Esta en un archivo php? utiliza `include('ruta/archivpo.php');` para referenciarlo antes de usarlo.

Comment: Antes del new Clase() tienes que incluir el archivo de la clase.

Comment: Y deberías mostrarnos el error que te sale como parte de la pregunta.

Comment: Sí, el archivo php lo tengo definido en el index, pero se ve que el archivo que llamo con ajax no lo reconoce, supongo que tendré que enviarle los datos desde el ajax para que sí lo reconozca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, era un problema con las rutas, que no me reconocía las rutas relativas... he tenido que poner rutas absolutas, lo que quizá sea un problema si lo subo al servidor, o cambio de sistema operativo

```
<div>
<?php
include("/home/usuario/public_html/miweb/clases/Clase.class.php");
$llamarClase=new Clase();

$llamarMetodo=$llamarClase->metodoClase();
?>
</div>
```